# Electric field strenght in material space

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I was thinking if we had two parallel plates seperated by $d$ meters and with  voltage difference of $V$, then one has an electric field between those plates with strenght,

$E=\frac{V}{d}$

Now, if one place a piece of wood between the plates for instance, would the electric field straight change? How would it change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "piece of wood", you mean a nonconducting dielectric, because a  piece of moist wood would make things quite complicated.

The answer depends on whether the voltage is fixed (capacitor connected to a battery) or whether the charge is fixed (capacitor was charged and then disconnected).

With a fixed voltage, $E$ stays the same, but extra charge flows into the capacitor.

With a fixed charge, the voltage will drop and $E$ will drop along with it.